# What is meant with the IBM cloud term resource_ID

Tags: ibm-cloud

In IBM cloud some of the documentation refer to resource_ID for example in
the command "ibmcloud resource reclamation-restore resource_ID".

When I look at the info of my resource, I find a CRN and a GUID. Which one is is it? Or is there something else. It is my impression that it is different to service-instance which is used in other parts of the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the resource ID is the [GUID (globally unique identifier)](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/overview?topic=overview-glossary#x2390455). The [cloud resource name (CRN)](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-crn) is used to name a resource in unique way and often includes the GUID, the service type (Watson Assistant, Db2, Cloudant or something like this), the region and other information.

It could be that in some (JSON) objects, the crn is sometimes denoted as ID. But the actual resource ID is the GUID.

For resource reclamation the [CLI documentation mentions the GUID as resource ID](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibmcloud_commands_resource#ibmcloud_resource_reclamations).

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by data_henrik, the resource ID is the guid from the resource's CRN.  If you use the command, ibmcloud resource reclamations, it will show you the guid in a column of the output